# HtmlWebpackPlugin How to include partials?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need kinda `gulp-rigger` for my webpack.

And I'm trying to use HtmlWebpackPlugin to achieve it.

In my webpack.config.js i have:

`const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');`

And I've included it in plugins section:

```
plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),
        // ...
    ]
```

Then in my index.html I'm trying to include file from partial dir, like so:

```
<div>${require('./partial/somepart.html')}</div>
```

But I see plain text in html file: ${require('./partial/somepart.html')}

What is wrong and how can I include html files in?

[webpack config](https://github.com/oleg-webdev/jstarter/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

Comment: with your *.html loader you disable the lodash interpolation normally done by HtmlWebpackPlugin. Have a look here: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md

Comment: I tried, it doesnt work